# Objective-C protocol delegate not working

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols

I want to send back an array of objects to myViewController from myRenderer

In myRenderer.h:

```
@protocol myProtocol;

@interface myRenderer : NSObject
     @property (weak) id <myProtocol> myDelegate;
@end

@protocol myProtocol <NSObject>
     - (void)sendToMyViewController : (NSMutableArray *) objects;
@end
```

In myRenderer.mm  (C++ / objective-c code):

```
@implementation myRenderer

@synthesize myDelegate;
.
.
.
-(void) sendObjects  
{
    [myDelegate sendToMyViewController : objects];

    Problem:
    myDelegate is always <nil>; = (id) 0x0

}
.
.
.
@end
```

in myViewController.h:

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController <myProtocol>
.
.
.
@end
```

in myViewController.m:

```
@implementation myViewController
.
.
.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    renderer = [[MyRenderer alloc] init];   
    renderer.myDelegate = self;
}
.
.
.

-(void) sendToMyViewController : (NSMutableArray *) objects
{
    // do something with objects

    Problem:
    this method is never called !!!
}
.
.
.
@end
```

Problem:
myDelegate is always nil; equal to (id) 0x0 and
sendToMyViewController never called.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: can you post your `renderer` object declaration in your `ViewController`?

Comment: Try to replace this - weak with strong in myreneder.h

Comment: @User511 the delegate should be weak and not strong, because if is strong  you are creating a retain cycle, and the delegate object will never be deallocated retaining also the viewController in memory

Comment: @ReinierMelian i agree with you, but here it seems the `weak` reference gets deallocated.

Comment: @Brain Scherady what attribute you set to your `renderer`?

Comment: @PratikJamariya that seems to do with the fact that maybe the render declaration in the ViewController is weak or assign I am assuming that the render is begin deallocating after the viewDidLoad scope

Comment: @PratikJamariya that is why I asked in my first comment about that declaration

Comment: oops, i missed that, my bad!

Comment: @PratikJamariya not problem, anyway the OP is missing, we are discussing his issue and hi is missing lol

Comment: Haha :D !! @ReinierMelian i think our discussion may help OP and he might solve his issue with our discussion :P

Comment: @BrianScherady can you post your `renderer` object declaration in your `ViewController`?

Comment: I am using simply:
@implementation myViewController
{
    MyRenderer *renderer;
}

Comment: @ReinierMelian, OP is using iVar and the default reference of iVar is `__strong` if i'm not wrong.

Comment: Its easy to check, @BrianScherady in the `viewDidAppear` check if `self.renderer` is `nil` please and let us know

Comment: when `sendObjects` method is called?

Comment: Did you override initilize method to myrender class?

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialize self
    }
    return self;
}

Comment: Setting a breakpoint just after:     renderer.myDelegate = self ;    in myVieController.m - I get renderer not nil and myDelegate also not nil.

Comment: YES ! I initilize myrender class? - In myRender.mm I have (instancetype)init { self = [super init]; if (self) { // Initialize self } return self; } - Does it reset myDelegate to nil? If yes what should I do?

Comment: Mmmmm! (instancetype)init { ... does not seem to be the cause of the problem; I commented it out, but it did not help.

Comment: @BrianScherady It's better if you can add full code of these 2 classes. The code in your question doesn't cause problem.

Comment: In `viewDidLoad` after setting it up could you `NSLog()` `renderer` using the `%p` (that shows the pointer value) format? Similarly in `sendObjects` log `self` using `%p`. Do both logs print the same of a different value? If the latter you have multiple `MyRender` instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

@CRD thank you for the hint!

There was indeed multiple MyRender instances, reducing them to a single instance solved the problem.